# $find("<%= RadComboBox.ClientID %>") returns null after using an asp:button as the ControlID of a telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl

Tags: javascript, telerik, radgrid, radcombobox, radajaxmanager

.Net 4.0
Telerik RadControls for ASP.NET Ajax version: 2013.3.1015.40

I'm using telerik:RadAjaxManager to update a RadGrid and RadComboBox after calling a server method via an asp:button. Once the grid has loaded, it calls the below javascript which is a snippet of the function that checks for any checked boxes client side. If I use the asp:button as the AjaxControlID to update RadComboBox, the method updates the combobox but var ddl returns null and I get the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'get_items' of null". However, if I update the RadComboBox via the OnNeedDataSource event of the updating RadGrid, I get the opposite. RadComboBox doesn't update, even though the method ran, but ddl populates as expected and the javascript methods can run.

```
function GridLoaded(sender, args) {
    var ddl = $find("<%= RadComboBox.ClientID %>");
    var items = ddl.get_items();
    ...
}
```

Which evaluates to:

```
function GridLoaded(sender, args) {
    var ddl = $find("ctl00_PrimaryContent_RadComboBox");
    var items = ddl.get_items();
    ...
}
```

I've tried encapsulating the javascript section in a RadCodeBlock and RadScriptBlock based on numerous other presented solutions with no improvement.

This functionality is working on a separate page with the only difference being the ComboBox is called from OnSelectedIndexChanged from one RadGrid to update another RadGrid.

I've checked here with no solution.
[telerik RadComboBox find Returns null - why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4069145/telerik-radcombobox-find-returns-null-why)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally <strike>figured this one out</strike> got it working.

Apparently, RadAjaxManager wants to update the ComboBox as well for everything to work together.

```
<telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager" runat="server" UpdatePanelsRenderMode="Inline">
    <AjaxSettings>
        <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="RadAjaxManager">
            <UpdatedControls>
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadComboBox" />
                <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid" />
            </UpdatedControls>
        </telerik:AjaxSetting>
    ...
    </AjaxSettings>
</telerik:RadAjaxManager>
```

If anyone can provide me a credible reason as to why this is, I will gladly mark it as the answer. Otherwise, I hope this prevents frustration for someone else.